# CKEditor, mathematics and content filter

Tags: javascript, math, ckeditor

I have configured CKEditor to remove all margin, color and font styles.

Here's CKEditor config :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Add WIRIS to the plugin list
    config.extraPlugins += (config.extraPlugins.length == 0 ? '' : ',') + 'ckeditor_wiris';
    // Allow all elements
    config.allowedContent = {
        $1: {
            // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
            elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
            attributes: true,
            styles: true,
            classes: true
        }
    };
    // Disallow font, margin, color styles and span elements
    config.disallowedContent = '*{font*}; *{margin*}; *{color*}; span;';
};
```

I'm using WIRIS plugin to create math equations. When I create a math equation with this plugin, I can see the equation in CKEditor and when I save it, it's saved as intended. 
But when I want to edit, the equation is no longer a math equation but only simple text. 
I think my config is removing math elements keeping only text. But I don't know what's wrong with my config since I allowed all HTML elements only disallowing element I don't want. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a hacky way to do it by adding this to config.js :

```
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'math[xmlns]; maction; maligngroup; malignmark; menclose; merror; mfenced; mfrac; mglyph; mi;' +
    'mlabeledtr; mlogdiv; mmultiscripts; mn; mo; mover; mpadded; mphantom; mroot; mrow; ms; mscarries; mscarry;' +
    'msgroup; mstack; msline; mspace; msqrt; msrow; mstack; mstyle; msub; msup; msubsup; mtable; mtd; mtext; mtr;' +
    'munder; munderover; semantics; annotation; annotation-xml;';
```